# University chair titles

Tags: usage, université

Bonjour,

Comment traduiriez-vous un poste de professeur universitaire qui mentionne une particularité dans le titre, par exemple pour un professeur spécialiste de l'interprétation néo-testamentaire: "Thomas R. Schreiner, James Buchanan Harrison Professor of New Testament Interpretation"? (le professeur en question étant Thomas R. Schreiner)?

Ma question porte sur le "James Buchanan Harrison".

D'avance merci pour votre aide!

Comment: Son éditeur français utilise *de*: [*professeur d'interprétation du Nouveau Testament*](https://maisonbible.fr/fr/60924_schreiner-thomas-r). Mais quand *professeur* est utilisé comme titre universitaire (et pas comme profession) on utilise aussi *en".

Comment: Aux Etats Unis, on donne souvent des noms aux chaires dans certaines universités.

Comment: Le terme *professeur d'[exégèse](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ex%C3%A9g%C3%A8se_biblique) du nouveau testament* à l'air d'être assez répandu également.

Comment: Notons qu'à l'université, on utilise de façon tout à fait ordinaire les termes néotestamentaire et vétérotestamentaire.

Answer (score 2):

On peut dire

> Thomas R. Schreiner, professeur titulaire de la chaire d'interprétation du nouveau testament « James Buchanan Harrison »

ou, selon le sens,

> Thomas R. Schreiner, professeur d'interprétation du nouveau testament, titulaire de la chaire « James Buchanan Harrison ».

Comment: Merci beaucoup!